# How to access pip3 with two Python3.x versions in Windows10 Path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, environment-variables

I have added two Python versions to my path.

```
C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\
C:\Program Files\Python38\
C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Program Files\Python37\
```

Within each `\Scripts` directory are these pip executables:

Program Files/Python38/Scripts 
                                                                                                                                                                                            ├── easy_install-3.8.exe
                                                                                                                                                                     ├── easy_install.exe
                                                                                                                                                                         ├── f2py.exe
                                                                                                                                                                                 ├── pip-script.py
                                                                                                                                                                            ├── pip.exe
                                                                                                                                                                                  ├── pip3-script.py
                                                                                                                                                                           ├── pip3.8-script.py
                                                                                                                                                                         ├── pip3.8.exe
                                                                                                                                                                               └── pip3.exe

.Program Files/Python37/Scripts
                                                                                                                                                                                            ├── easy_install-3.7.exe
                                                                                                                                                                     ├── easy_install.exe
                                                                                                                                                                         ├── pip.exe
                                                                                                                                                                                  ├── pip3.7.exe
                                                                                                                                                                               └── pip3.exe

I cannot seem to use `pip3` since adding Python3.7 to my Path environment variable.

```
C:\Users\User>python38
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.         
>>>
```

```
C:\Users\User>python38 pip3.8
python38: can't open file 'pip3.8': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

```
C:\Users\User>pip3.8
'pip3.8' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Users\User>python37 
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.         
>>>
```

```
C:\Users\User>python38 pip3.7
python38: can't open file 'pip3.7': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

```
C:\Users\User>pip3.7
'pip3.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I use pip3?

Comment: Did you try `pip3.7` or `pip3.8` alone on the command line?  I don't see that in your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
python-3.7 -m pip install pack
```

Where pack your packet